# how to make shared library an executable

Tags: c, operating-system, shared-libraries, executable, x86-64

I was searching for asked question. i saw this link https://hev.cc/2512.html which is doing exactly the same thing which I want. But there is no explanation of whats going on. I am also confused whether shared library with out main() can be made executable if yes how? I can guess i have to give global main() but know no details. Any further easy reference and guidance is much appreciated

I am working on x86-64 64 bit Ubuntu with kernel 3.13

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/223385/why-and-how-are-some-shared-libraries-runnable-as-though-they-are-executables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see how this is useful for anything.  You could always achieve the same functionality from having a `main` in a separate binary that links against that library.  Making a single file that works as both is solidly in the realm of "silly computer tricks".  There's no benefit I can see to having a `main` embedded in the library, even if it's a test harness or something.

There might possible be some performance reasons, like not having function calls go through the indirection of the PLT.

---

In that example, the shared library is also a valid ELF executable, because it has a quick-and-dirty entry-point that grabs the args for `main` from where [the ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) says they go (i.e. copies them from the stack into registers).  It also arranges for the ELF interpreter to be set correctly.  It will only work on x86-64, because no definition is provided for `init_args` for other platforms.

I'm surprised it actually works; I thought all the crap the usual CRT (startup) code does was actually needed for stdio to work properly.  It looks like it doesn't initialize `extern char **environ;`, since it only gets `argc` and `argv` from the stack, not `envp`.

Anyway, when run as an executable, it has everything needed to be a valid dynamically-linked executable: an entry-point which runs some code and exits, an interpreter, and a dependency on libc.  (ELF shared libraries can depend on (i.e. link against) other ELF shared libraries, in the same way that executables can).

---

When used as a library, it just works as a normal library containing some function definitions.  None of the stuff that lets it work as an executable (entry point and interpreter) is even looked at.

I'm not sure why you don't get an error for multiple definitions of `main`, since it isn't declared as a ["weak" symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_symbol).  I guess shared-lib definitions are only looked for when there's a reference to an undefined symbol.  So `main()` from `call.c` is used instead of `main()` from `libtest.so` because `main` already has a definition before the linker looks at `libtest`.

Answer (score 3):

This is fundamentally not sensible.

A shared library generally has no task it performs that can be used as it's equivalent of a `main()` function.  The primary goal is to allow separate management and implementation of common code operations, and on systems that operate that way to allow a single code file to be loaded and shared, thereby reducing memory overhead for application code that uses it.

An executable file is designed to have a single point of entry from which it performs all the operations related to completing a well defined task.  Different OSes have different requirements for that entry point.  A shared library normally has no similar underlying function.

So in order to (usefully) convert a shared library to an executable you must also define ( and generate code for ) a task which can be started from a single entry point.

The code you linked to is starting with the source code to the library and explicitly codes a main() which it invokes via the entry point function.  If you did not have the source code for a library you could, in theory, hack a new file from a shared library ( in the absence of security features to prevent this in any given OS ), but it would be an odd thing to do.

But in practical terms you would not deploy code in this manner.  Instead you would code a shared library as a shared library.  If you wanted to perform some task you would code a separate executable that linked to that library and code.  Trying to tie the two together defeats the purpose of writing the library and distorts the structure, implementation and maintenance of that library and the application.  Keep the application and the library apart.

Comment: I am trying to write reference monitor that loads binary in idiosyncratic way. shared library is a sensible solution in this situation. Am I right? yes you are right shared library will generate daemon to further restrict the execution of loaded process.

Comment: `/lib/ld.so` is almost always both an executable and a linkable shared object. In the light of this, I'd say that "fundamentally not sensible" is not a correct qualifier for this kind of solution.

Answer (score 0):

- To create shared Dynamic Library with Example.

> Suppose with there are three files are : sum.o mul.o and print.o
>
> Shared library name " libmno.so "

```
cc -shared -o libmno.so sum.o mul.o print.o
```

> and compile with

```
cc main.c ./libmno.so
```